# How can I set a catch all route as the very last route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm building a basic CMS with SEO slugs, so I want a catch all at the end of my routes to get the slug. So at the end of my routes file I added:

```
Route::get('/{page?}', ['as' => 'Page', 'middleware' => 'web', 'uses' => 'PageController@index']);
```

Which works fine, until I added [Laravel File Manager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager), which has routes of its own. These routes are added **after** all of the routes in my main routes file. So now my catch all picks up anything meant for the file manager.

How can I load all other routes, including those in other vendor folders, before running the catch all? Is there a way I can state that the route must not match any route prefixed with `laravel-filemanager`? I've not been able to find anything on this in the Laravel documentation or through Google.

As requested here is my app providers:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,
    Caffeinated\Modules\ModulesServiceProvider::class,
    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
    Spatie\Activitylog\ActivitylogServiceProvider::class,
    Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,
    Unisharp\Ckeditor\ServiceProvider::class,
    Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider::class,

],
```

Comment: can you list app providers? one solution maybe to list filemanager service provider before the route service provider

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili I've added my app providers for you, the file manager is the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply try to reorder the service providers in app.php like this:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */

    Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider::class,
    ... 
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    ... 

],
```

Anyway I always write `RouteServiceProvider` at the end of list, if not special case

Comment: Thank you, didn't realise that the order of providers affected the order that routes are loaded.

Comment: Welcome, glad to help you. laravel is big, so you can't realize everything until you have the problem of that case ;))